# Using CSS to make arrow-headed div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pseudo-element

I am trying to implement a arrow-headed div. Below is the part of the code that is relevant to the post/question. I have been trying to figure out how to get this done for a while now but no success.

I have a grandparent div, a parent div with a child as follows

```
<div className="main-segment-container">
   <div className="panel panel-default segment-select-box">
      <div className="panel-header segment-select-box-header">MAIN SEGMENT</div>
      <div className="panel-body segment-select-box-body">
        <div className=has-subsegments'>
          <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" value={checkedSegment.category_id} onChange={this.segmentChecked} />{' '}
             &nbsp;
          <label className="form-check-label">{checkedSegment.name}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve (notice the arrowhead):

[image]

I am able to achieve this with this css:

```
.main-segment-container{
   width: 100%
 }

.has-subsegments{
   background-color: #215C64;
   width: 100%;
   color: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   height: 30px;
}

.segment-select-box {
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  /* max-height: 400px; */
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  position: relative;
}
.segment-select-box-body{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.has-subsegments::after{
  content: "";
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 21px solid #215C64;
  width: 0;
  height: 0px;
  right: -20px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

**Problem:**

When I use the css above, the `.has-subsegments` element seems to be at a fixed position when I scroll. Like this:

[image]

**Question**

How do I implement scroll without removing the element from the normal position?

**Note:**

1. When i remove `scroll` from `.segment-select-box-body` class, everything works perfect but the children list becomes very long, therefore a scroll is needed.
2. adding `position: relative;` to `.segment-select-box-body` class makes the :after pseudo-element invisible.

**EDIT**

See JSFIDDLE here : https://jsfiddle.net/uuwhndgu/16/

Comment: would it be possible for you to put this into a codepen or a jsfiddle?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind right now is the `position: absolute` on `.has-subsegments`

Comment: @PatrickManser see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uuwhndgu/16/

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: ok, i will take a look, thanks

Comment: @PatrickManser...does this mean also that the panel-header can not be at fixed position?

Comment: ok never mind, i fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Thanks for posting the jsfiddle. I don't think, what you're trying to achieve is possible the way you are trying to do it.

I updated the fiddle with a suggested workaround/fix: https://jsfiddle.net/uuwhndgu/34/

what I did, is giving the wrapping col a little more width (you probably would have to either increase the col to `.col-md-3` or decrease the width of `.segment-select-box` a little. You probably need to do the latter anyway), a `max-height`of 200px and a `overflow-y: scroll;`. I set the width of `.segment-select-box` to 90% and changed `position: absolute;`of `.has-subsegments` to `position: relative;`. I don't know if this helps you but I BELIEVE, that there aren't many ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

---

**Original answer**

I am not quite sure how you intend this thing to behave. But if the highlighted entry (the one with the arrow) just ought to stay where it was, I think you can simply replace `position: absolute;` with `position: relative;` in your `.has-subsegments` class. Now, I wasn't able to recreate this anything close to perfectly, because it's a react app, but still, you should get the idea:

with `position: absolute;`  on `.has-subsegments`

[image]

with `position: relative;` on `.has-subsegments`

[image]

Comment: does this mean also that the panel-header can not be at fixed position?